# Prepend all inbound links on a page, and change target for all outbound links?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Needing some direction and/or sample jquery code for the following:

1. Prepend all inbound? links on a page with "?id=t".
2. Change the target for all outbound links to open in new page/tab (target="_blank").

This will need to happen after the page has loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested but try this:

For #1:

```
$('a').each(function() {

   var that = $(this);
   var href = that.attr('href');

   if(href.search('yourdomain.com') != -1) {      
      that.attr('href', href+'?id=t');
   }

});
```

For #2:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    return this.hostname && this.hostname !== location.hostname;
}).each(function() {
    var rel = $(this).attr('rel');
    if(rel) {
        $(this).attr('rel', rel + ' external');
    } else {
        $(this).attr('rel', 'external');
    }
});

$('a[rel*=external]').click( function() {
    window.open(this.href);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'll give this a go and report back.

Comment: Works Perfect.  Thanks.  Love this site.

Answer (score 0):

First assign a class "inbound" to all inbound links and "outbound" to all outbound links
$(document).ready(function(){

```
$('a.inbound').each(function(){
var h = $(this).attr('href');
$(this).attr('href',h+'?id=t');
});

$('a.outbound').attr('target','_blank');


});
```

Comment: Sorry, just wasn't realistic to add a class to and differentiate between all inbound and outbound links on my site.  Thanks.